# Does anybody knows why my tool is expecting an "arg1" in Langchain?

Tags: python, large-language-model, py-langchain

Well few days ago my code was working perfectly but today I'm having this error so many times in console:

`TypeError: SQLFilterTool._run() got an unexpected keyword argument 'arg1'`

The agent that I use is invoking my tool but in this way:

```
> Entering new AgentExecutor chain...

Invoking: `filter_user_query` with `{'arg1': 'average temperature recorded in August 2023 for computer ..... '}`
```

And as you can see, is entering with an "arg1", but don't really know whay is this happening

I make this tool:

```
from langchain.tools import BaseTool

class SQLFilterTool(BaseTool):
    name = "filter_user_query"
    description = SQL_FILTER_TOOL

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def _run(self, query_input: str):
        return sql_filter_vanna(query_input)

    def _arun(self, query_input: str):
        return sql_filter_vanna(query_input)
```

and also I tried to put the arg1 in arguments but is not working, so does anybody knows what is happening or maybe I'm doing something wrong, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the tool decorator like this and is working fine:

```
from langchain.agents import tool

@tool
def sql_filter_vanna(question) -> str:
    '''
    tool description . . .
    '''
    vn = VannaDefault(model=model, api_key=api_key)
    vn.run_sql
    res = vn.generate_sql(question=question)
    return res
```

But if you find a way to use tool decorator with more arguments or maybe found other way, let me know please, thanks